# Date on message box - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I performed code below to show date on message box. However, the value in code is not the same with showing value on message box. Could you please help me to know the reason?

code VB:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim birthday As Date
birthday = 27 / 11 / 1992 'dd/mm/yyy
abc = MsgBox("Birthday: " & Format(birthday, "dd/mm/yyyy"), 3, "Choose option")
End Sub
```

[message box result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G72By.png)

Comment: `27/11/1992` = 0.00123220 (because `/` means 'divide') and the datetime representation of 0.00123220 is `00:01:46` - I think you mean to wrap that in quotes (`"`) so that it's treated as a string instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
 birthday = "27 / 11 / 1992"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I get it.